# Oracle SQLLDR LOBFILE

Tags: oracle, clob

We're trying to load a file that contains about 40,000 records.   Each record is basically one long CLOB value, up for 100,000 characters.   I'm trying to use SQL Loader like this:

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE '/u01/TSDEV/data/data.txt'
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE commentary
(clob_filename       FILLER CHAR(100),
 value               LOBFILE(clob_filename) TERMINATED BY EOF)
```

But, I am getting this on every record:

```
Path used:      Conventional
SQL*Loader-502: unable to open data file 
'[{"cid":"1","ts_id":"1","group_id":"0","c_subject":"Above is the summary of new trades across our Tr' for field VALUE table COMMENTARY
SQL*Loader-553: file not found
SQL*Loader-509: System error: No such file or directory
SQL*Loader-502: unable to open data file 
'[{"cid":"2","ts_id":"1","group_id":"0","c_subject":"Is Italy the Next Greece?","c_message":"<p><span' for field VALUE table COMMENTARY
```

So, it sees the file, because it displays the content.   But why the error?  None of the data will load.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the format of data.txt? Is it just a list of filenames and each clob in its own file? Or does data.txt have one line per clob with newline as the indicator of the end of each clob? Seems like the latter is true and that sql*loader is using the first 100 characters of your clobs as the file name.

Comment: Why would you load 40,000 logical "records" into a single LOB? Oracle's relational, it is intended that each record would be a row in a table, and each row be comprised of discrete columns with one data value per column. SQL*Loader has a rich set of controls that enable parsing almost any file into Oracle's relational row-column format. If you try to stick an entire file into a LOB column, you lose almost all relational functionality of a modern RDBMS and it becomes a "data dump"

Comment: What I am aiming to do, is to load all these into a CLOB.  Ok, then I have a function which will read this data, which is actually JSON data, and parse it and load it.   So, that part I believe works.    Just why is SQLLDR not working??   Why is it throwing such an error?

Comment: And, it is not all 40,000 into 1 CLOB.   If is all 40,000 into 40,000 records, each of a CLOB column.

Comment: SQLLDR should just take the input and load it.   But something is happening that stops it and throws that erroe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is just inline, then you do not use LOBFILE.  LOBFILE is for when the data contains the ***name*** of the file which contains the LOB data, ie, one file per line in the SQL Loader datafile. For inline data, you nominate a large CHAR size, eg

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'sample.dat' 
INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   (name        CHAR(25),
    mylobdata   CHAR(10000))
```

If your LOB data contains all sorts of data (newlines, delimiters etc), then you would need to prefix/suffix the data with some known value and then let SQL Loader know about it, eg

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'sample.dat' 
INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   (name        CHAR(25),
    mylobdata   CHAR(10000) ENCLOSED BY '<startlob>' AND '<endlob>')
```

Comment: Tried your second example, and it worked!   Many thanks!!!